# My icon Fonts are not loading and it returns CORS error after I deployed my site from localhost to live

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, server, hosting

I am a beginner. I developed a website on localhost . When I deployed the website on a live domain. My icon fonts are returning "blocked by CORS policy..." error.  I don't know much about CORS. Why it worked on my localhost but it does not on live domain?. How can i overcome that?.

I saw answers for bigger problems related to CORS, however I could not find a solution to this problem  from it, I appreciate your help. Thanks.

I read about installing a plugin in the browser but that not what i want, I want to learn how to get rid of that issue without installing browser extensions because that's not ideal for clients

This is my htaccess code

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: How did you migrate it? Link to the website?

Comment: I migrated it via FTP and imported the database and replace the db table values properly. I forgot to update the wp_option table that is why it was pointing towards my localhost to get resource. Now it is okay, Thanks for your willingness to help me